# Accidentially forgot to switch branch, how to unmerge branches?

Tags: git

I have three branches main A, B and C accidentally started from B.

```
A1----------A
 \
--Bn
   \
   C0-------Cn
```

C starts where B ends, A just merged into B.
And I want it to be like:

```
-Bn
 /
A1----------An
 \
 C0-------Cn
```

C starts from A.
I mean changes made by B should not be in C.
What can I do?

Comment: Both branch diagrams actually look the same to me.  Can you edit your question and point out what you want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just edited.

Comment: Have a look at git cherry pick - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick. You want to apply commit C to branch A and then revert commit C from branch B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit.

I see your edited question.
Now I understand you better.

You have to create a new branch from A1 and then cherry-pick all commits from branch C

Remove old branch C.

Comment: is there faster way to do that?